# Why use Unique when Primary key on same key is already defined

Tags: mysql, primary-key, unique-key

While reading Database Systems, I have encountered through a query as shown below:

```
 CREATE TABLE works (
    eid       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    did       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pcttime   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY ( eid,
    did ),
    UNIQUE ( eid ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( did )
        REFERENCES dept
);
```

Since primary key on eid,did is already defined, why would we require unique on eid? Because each eid,did pair is already unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary key is on two columns, so you could still have non-unique eids. E.g.,

```
eid   did
1     1
1     2
```

This doesn't violate your primary key, but would violate your unique constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!